# writing to registers - naming convention in stm32

Tags: stm32

Ive been trying to setup an ADC manually within SMT32cubeIDE for an STM32F0103K6. I think i know which registers and flags i need, but I can't seem to write to any of them because all the names are wrong - ? I tried using the names in the SFR view in cubeIDE like -

```
 ADC ->CR |= 1<<ADEN; // enable ADC
 ADC ->ADC_SMPR |= 1<<0 | 1<<1; // speed divider select
 ADC ->ADC_CHSELR |= 1<<0 | 1<<1; // set sequence to adc0, adc1
 ADC ->ADC_CFGR1 |= 1<<DISCEN; //discontinuous mode
 ADC ->ADC_CR |= 1<<2; // start conversion
```

but the compiler doesn't recognise any of them. The names in the reference manual are all the same except they have ADC (i.e. ADC_CR) and none of the names of the bits seem to be recognised either.

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s easy. Find the CMSIS header file(s) and use the correct identifiers.
Usually register bit definitions look like ADC_CR1_DISCEN.

Comment: where do i find the CMSIS header files?

Comment: Should be part of your (generated ?) project source files. Try to find the .h file containg ADC_CFGR1_DISCEN or just DISCEN.